# What is a Python function that is similar to R's simulate() function

Tags: python, simulation, arima, forecast

R's simulate function takes a model fit and the number of simulations desired to generate a vector of simulations. I would like to know Python's equivalent. Specifically, I would like to pass an Arima model fit to this function to generate 1000 simulations for every future date in a test set.

Some related info on `simulate()` and simulations from Arima.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/simulate

https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/simulating-from-a-specified-seasonal-arima-model/

Comment: That sounds like a very specific function. Python is more of a general purpose language, not one that has specialties like that built in. There may be a library (or multiple), but asking for library recommendations is offtopic here. I don't know of one off the top of my head either.

Comment: Knowing a library would be nice, but I would not mind a more general approach. I just want to know if there is any way to generate simulations from an arima fit.

Comment: Write a function corresponding to your model, then call the function the desired number of times with a loop.  If you do that in a list comprehension, you get a list of simulation results with which you can do whatever you want.